# Simple Zillow API call gives white screen

Tags: zillow

I can't seem to get out of the gate.
I have the following which gives nothing but white screen...

```
    <?php 
 $url = "http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetDemographics.htm?zws-id=<my api      key>&state=CO&city=Denver&neighborhood=Stapleton";
 $data = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($url));
 print_r($data); 
?>
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

thanx for your help!!

Comment: Do you need an API key defined in the URL?

Comment: Nevermind I see it now after editing the post. You needed to define that block as 'code' :)

Comment: sorry, new to stack overflow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me, maybe you don't have libxml installed with PHP?  The blank screen could be the result of a fatal error.

Try changing your script to:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL); // log all errors
ini_set('display_errors', 'on'); // display errors in output, rather than to error_log

$url = "http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetDemographics.htm?zws-id=<my api      key>&state=CO&city=Denver&neighborhood=Stapleton";
$data = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($url));
print_r($data);
```

The first two lines will likely result in some sort of error message being displayed which would be a blank page if [display_errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) is off.

Comment: hmm - I tried your code with error lines commented out and it worked?  Strange, but thanx a ton for your help...

Comment: No problem, another possibility is that file_get_contents failed or only a partial request was loaded and $data was null in which case print_r wouldn't show anything.  The error reporting lines can be helpful in development because often PHP installs (particularly on web hosts) are configured with display_errors off so you often won't see warnings, notices or errors in your code.